# Colab cannot import DownloadModel from datasets

Tags: google-colaboratory, huggingface-datasets

[image: colab_error]
The problem is shown here, it said it can't import this module, but I tried it on my own computer it works
I face this error when I tried to use colab to fine-tune a model. I import evaluate module and it shows me a problem, the python env is 3.8 and the datasets version is 2.8.0, if there is anyone can help? thanks a lot!

then I try with

```
!pip install datasets
```

and

```
from datasets import DownloadModel
```

, it shows the same problem.

Comment: In the screenshot says `DownLoadMode` - it should be `downloadmodel`.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrote `from datasets import DownloadModel` but probably you want to import DownloadMode (without 'l'). Try: `from datasets import DownloadMode`.

I have the same error in `Jupyter Notebook 6.4.0` with `Python 3.9.2` and `dataset 2.12.0`. I don't know exacly why I got this error, but after restart (from menu Kernel choose "Restart & Clear Output") all works fine.